# How can I accelerate repeated interpolation of a very large dataset?

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation, interpolation

I am solving a 4D time-dependent PDE using a discretization method. My query is not about solving this; because I am doing it in the following code. The code is OK and it works fine. 
My main problem occurs when I want to use the solution of this PDE (its interpolation `solution1[]`) in a loop over the grid of points, i.e., the last piece of the written code. This part is quite slow.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
t1 = AbsoluteTime[];
(***************PARAMETER SETTINGS***************)
TT = 5.; m1 = 10; m2 = 10; m3 = 10; m4 = 10;
size = m1*m2*m3*m4;  
Print["The size of the system of ODEs is = ", size];
roRr = -0.4; roRz = -0.15; roRy = -0.15; rorz = 0.5; rory = 0.5; royz \
= 0.25;  
sigmaR = 0.01; sigmar = 0.08; sigmaz = 0.1; sigmay = 0.4;
gammar = 0.08; gammaz = 0.08;
r = 0.02; θ = -210.; a = 0.08; b = 0.1; a1 = 0.08; b1 = 0.1; e \
= 1.15; κ = 0.0001;
(***************DOMAIN DISCRETIZATION***************)
Rmin = 0.; Rmax = 1.; rmin = 0.; rmax = 1.; ymin = -6.; ymax = 0.; \
zmin = 0.; zmax =(*14e*)4;
Print[{Rmin, Rmax}, "\[Cross]", {rmin, rmax}, "\[Cross]" {ymin, ymax},
   "\[Cross]", {zmin, zmax}];

e1 = 0.45;
nx = xgrid1 = Range[Rmin, Rmax, (Rmax - Rmin)/(m1 - 1)];
ny = ygrid1 = Range[rmin, rmax, (rmax - rmin)/(m2 - 1)];
nz = zgrid1 = Range[ymin, ymax, (ymax - ymin)/(m3 - 1)];
nw = wgrid1 = Range[zmin, zmax, (zmax - zmin)/(m4 - 1)];
origrid = Flatten[Outer[List, nx, ny, nz, nw], 3];

(***************FILLING SOME MATRICES***************)
Idx = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1.}, {m1, m1}, 0]; Idy = 
 SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1.}, {m2, m2}, 0]; 
Idz = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1.}, {m3, m3}, 0]; Idw = 
 SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1.}, {m4, m4}, 0];
DR = KroneckerProduct[(SparseArray@DiagonalMatrix@nx), Idy, Idz, Idw]; 
Dr = KroneckerProduct[Idx, (SparseArray@DiagonalMatrix@ny), Idz, Idw]; 
Dy = KroneckerProduct[Idx, Idy, (SparseArray@DiagonalMatrix@nz), Idw];
Dz = KroneckerProduct[Idx, Idy, Idz, (SparseArray@DiagonalMatrix@nw)];
Id = KroneckerProduct[Idx, Idy, Idz, Idw];

Dy2 = KroneckerProduct[Idx, Idy, (SparseArray@DiagonalMatrix@Exp[nz]),
    Idw];
(***************FOR FIRST SPATIAL VARIABLE***************)
hh = Differences[nx]; ww = 
 Table[hh[[i + 1]]/hh[[i]], {i, 1, Length[hh] - 1}];
{Min[hh], c = 6*Max[hh]}
A1d1 = Join[
   Table[(ww [[
      i - 1]] (-3 c^2 + hh[[i - 1]]^2 (-5 + 2 ww [[i - 1]])))/(
    3 c^2 hh[[i - 1]] (1 + ww [[i - 1]])), {i, 2, 
     m1 - 1}], { -(1/hh[[Length[hh]]]) + hh[[Length[hh]]]/c^2}];
A1d2 = Join[{-(1/hh[[1]]) + hh[[1]]/c^2}, 
   Table[-((2  hh[[i - 1]] (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]))/(3 c^2)) + (-1 + 
      ww[[i - 1]])/( hh[[i - 1]] ww[[i - 1]]), {i, 2, m1 - 1}], {1/
    hh[[Length[hh]]]}];
A1d3 = Join[{1/hh[[1]]}, 
   Table[(3/ww[[i - 1]] + (hh[[i - 1]]^2 (-2 + 5 ww[[i - 1]]))/c^2)/(
    3 hh[[i - 1]] (1 + ww[[i - 1]])), {i, 2, m1 - 1}]];
(*2nd*)
A3d1 = Join[
   Table[(3 hh[[
         i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])^2 (-1 + 
          ww[[i - 1]]) + (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 - 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 ww[[i - 1]]) - 
       hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
          hh[[i - 1]]) (1 + (-3 + ww[[i - 1]]) ww[[i - 1]]))/(c^2 hh[[
        i - 1]]^2 (-1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) (1 + 
         hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) ((1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) + 
         ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m1 - 1}], {0}];
A2d1 = Join[{(2 (3/hh[[1]]^2 + (5 + 2 (-2 + ww[[1]]) ww[[1]])/c^2))/(
    3 (1 + ww[[1]]))}, Table[
    ((1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 + 3 hh[[i - 1]]^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) - (2 c^2 + 
          3 hh[[i - 1]]^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
             hh[[i - 1]]) (3 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]))) ww[[
         i - 1]] + 
       hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) ww[[
         i - 1]]^2)/(c^2 hh[[
        i - 1]]^2 (-1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) (1 + 
         ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m1 - 1}], {-4/c^2}];
A2d2 = Join[{-4/c^2, (
    2 (-(3/hh[[1]]^2) + (-2 + ww[[1]] - 2 ww[[1]]^2)/c^2))/(
    3 ww[[1]])}, Table[
    1/(c^2 hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) ww[[
       i - 1]]) (hh[[
         i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])^2 (-1 + 
          ww[[i - 1]]) + (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 - 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 ww[[i - 1]]) - (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
          hh[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 + hh[[i - 1]]^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]) ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m1 - 1}], {2/c^2}];
A2d3 = Join[{2/c^2, (
    6 c^2 + 2 hh[[1]]^2 (2 + ww[[1]] (-4 + 5 ww[[1]])))/(
    3 c^2 hh[[1]]^2 ww[[1]] (1 + ww[[1]]))}, Table[
    ((1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) (2 c^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) - 
       hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
             hh[[i - 1]]) (3 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]))) ww[[
         i - 1]] + 
       3 hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) ww[[
         i - 1]]^2)/(c^2 hh[[i - 1]]^2 ww[[
        i - 1]] (1 + ww[[i - 1]]) ((1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) + 
         ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m1 - 1}]];

dudx = Chop@
   SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> A1d2, Band[{2, 1}] -> A1d1, 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> A1d3}, {m1, m1}];
d2udx2 = Chop@
   SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> A2d2, Band[{2, 1}] -> A2d1, 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> A2d3, Band[{3, 1}] -> A3d1}, {m1, m1}];

(***************FOR SECOND SPATIAL VARIABLE***************)
hh = Differences[ny]; ww = 
 Table[hh[[i + 1]]/hh[[i]], {i, 1, Length[hh] - 1}];
{Min[hh], c = 6*Max[hh]}
A1d1 = Join[
   Table[(ww [[
      i - 1]] (-3 c^2 + hh[[i - 1]]^2 (-5 + 2 ww [[i - 1]])))/(
    3 c^2 hh[[i - 1]] (1 + ww [[i - 1]])), {i, 2, 
     m2 - 1}], { -(1/hh[[Length[hh]]]) + hh[[Length[hh]]]/c^2}];
A1d2 = Join[{-(1/hh[[1]]) + hh[[1]]/c^2}, 
   Table[-((2  hh[[i - 1]] (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]))/(3 c^2)) + (-1 + 
      ww[[i - 1]])/( hh[[i - 1]] ww[[i - 1]]), {i, 2, m2 - 1}], {1/
    hh[[Length[hh]]]}];
A1d3 = Join[{1/hh[[1]]}, 
   Table[(3/ww[[i - 1]] + (hh[[i - 1]]^2 (-2 + 5 ww[[i - 1]]))/c^2)/(
    3 hh[[i - 1]] (1 + ww[[i - 1]])), {i, 2, m2 - 1}]];
(*2nd*)
A3d1 = Join[
   Table[(3 hh[[
         i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])^2 (-1 + 
          ww[[i - 1]]) + (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 - 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 ww[[i - 1]]) - 
       hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
          hh[[i - 1]]) (1 + (-3 + ww[[i - 1]]) ww[[i - 1]]))/(c^2 hh[[
        i - 1]]^2 (-1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) (1 + 
         hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) ((1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) + 
         ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m2 - 1}], {0}];
A2d1 = Join[{(2 (3/hh[[1]]^2 + (5 + 2 (-2 + ww[[1]]) ww[[1]])/c^2))/(
    3 (1 + ww[[1]]))}, Table[
    ((1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 + 3 hh[[i - 1]]^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) - (2 c^2 + 
          3 hh[[i - 1]]^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
             hh[[i - 1]]) (3 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]))) ww[[
         i - 1]] + 
       hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) ww[[
         i - 1]]^2)/(c^2 hh[[
        i - 1]]^2 (-1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) (1 + 
         ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m2 - 1}], {-4/c^2}];
A2d2 = Join[{-4/c^2, (
    2 (-(3/hh[[1]]^2) + (-2 + ww[[1]] - 2 ww[[1]]^2)/c^2))/(
    3 ww[[1]])}, Table[
    1/(c^2 hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) ww[[
       i - 1]]) (hh[[
         i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])^2 (-1 + 
          ww[[i - 1]]) + (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 - 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 ww[[i - 1]]) - (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
          hh[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 + hh[[i - 1]]^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]) ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m2 - 1}], {2/c^2}];
A2d3 = Join[{2/c^2, (
    6 c^2 + 2 hh[[1]]^2 (2 + ww[[1]] (-4 + 5 ww[[1]])))/(
    3 c^2 hh[[1]]^2 ww[[1]] (1 + ww[[1]]))}, Table[
    ((1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) (2 c^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) - 
       hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
             hh[[i - 1]]) (3 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]))) ww[[
         i - 1]] + 
       3 hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) ww[[
         i - 1]]^2)/(c^2 hh[[i - 1]]^2 ww[[
        i - 1]] (1 + ww[[i - 1]]) ((1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) + 
         ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m2 - 1}]];

dudy = Chop@
   SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> A1d2, Band[{2, 1}] -> A1d1, 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> A1d3}, {m2, m2}];
d2udy2 = Chop@
   SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> A2d2, Band[{2, 1}] -> A2d1, 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> A2d3, Band[{3, 1}] -> A3d1}, {m2, m2}];


(***************FOR THIRD SPATIAL VARIABLE***************)
hh = Differences[nz]; ww = 
 Table[hh[[i + 1]]/hh[[i]], {i, 1, Length[hh] - 1}];
{Min[hh], c = 6*Max[hh]}
A1d1 = Join[
   Table[(ww [[
      i - 1]] (-3 c^2 + hh[[i - 1]]^2 (-5 + 2 ww [[i - 1]])))/(
    3 c^2 hh[[i - 1]] (1 + ww [[i - 1]])), {i, 2, 
     m3 - 1}], { -(1/hh[[Length[hh]]]) + hh[[Length[hh]]]/c^2}];
A1d2 = Join[{-(1/hh[[1]]) + hh[[1]]/c^2}, 
   Table[-((2  hh[[i - 1]] (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]))/(3 c^2)) + (-1 + 
      ww[[i - 1]])/( hh[[i - 1]] ww[[i - 1]]), {i, 2, m3 - 1}], {1/
    hh[[Length[hh]]]}];
A1d3 = Join[{1/hh[[1]]}, 
   Table[(3/ww[[i - 1]] + (hh[[i - 1]]^2 (-2 + 5 ww[[i - 1]]))/c^2)/(
    3 hh[[i - 1]] (1 + ww[[i - 1]])), {i, 2, m3 - 1}]];
(*2nd*)
A3d1 = Join[
   Table[(3 hh[[
         i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])^2 (-1 + 
          ww[[i - 1]]) + (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 - 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 ww[[i - 1]]) - 
       hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
          hh[[i - 1]]) (1 + (-3 + ww[[i - 1]]) ww[[i - 1]]))/(c^2 hh[[
        i - 1]]^2 (-1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) (1 + 
         hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) ((1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) + 
         ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m3 - 1}], {0}];
A2d1 = Join[{(2 (3/hh[[1]]^2 + (5 + 2 (-2 + ww[[1]]) ww[[1]])/c^2))/(
    3 (1 + ww[[1]]))}, Table[
    ((1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 + 3 hh[[i - 1]]^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) - (2 c^2 + 
          3 hh[[i - 1]]^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
             hh[[i - 1]]) (3 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]))) ww[[
         i - 1]] + 
       hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) ww[[
         i - 1]]^2)/(c^2 hh[[
        i - 1]]^2 (-1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) (1 + 
         ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m3 - 1}], {-4/c^2}];
A2d2 = Join[{-4/c^2, (
    2 (-(3/hh[[1]]^2) + (-2 + ww[[1]] - 2 ww[[1]]^2)/c^2))/(
    3 ww[[1]])}, Table[
    1/(c^2 hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) ww[[
       i - 1]]) (hh[[
         i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])^2 (-1 + 
          ww[[i - 1]]) + (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 - 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 ww[[i - 1]]) - (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
          hh[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 + hh[[i - 1]]^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]) ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m3 - 1}], {2/c^2}];
A2d3 = Join[{2/c^2, (
    6 c^2 + 2 hh[[1]]^2 (2 + ww[[1]] (-4 + 5 ww[[1]])))/(
    3 c^2 hh[[1]]^2 ww[[1]] (1 + ww[[1]]))}, Table[
    ((1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) (2 c^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) - 
       hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
             hh[[i - 1]]) (3 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]))) ww[[
         i - 1]] + 
       3 hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) ww[[
         i - 1]]^2)/(c^2 hh[[i - 1]]^2 ww[[
        i - 1]] (1 + ww[[i - 1]]) ((1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) + 
         ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m3 - 1}]];

dudz = Chop@
   SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> A1d2, Band[{2, 1}] -> A1d1, 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> A1d3}, {m3, m3}];
d2udz2 = Chop@
   SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> A2d2, Band[{2, 1}] -> A2d1, 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> A2d3, Band[{3, 1}] -> A3d1}, {m3, m3}];

(***************FOR FOURTH SPATIAL VARIABLE***************)
hh = Differences[nw]; ww = 
 Table[hh[[i + 1]]/hh[[i]], {i, 1, Length[hh] - 1}];
{Min[hh], c = 6*Max[hh]}
A1d1 = Join[
   Table[(ww [[
      i - 1]] (-3 c^2 + hh[[i - 1]]^2 (-5 + 2 ww [[i - 1]])))/(
    3 c^2 hh[[i - 1]] (1 + ww [[i - 1]])), {i, 2, 
     m4 - 1}], { -(1/hh[[Length[hh]]]) + hh[[Length[hh]]]/c^2}];
A1d2 = Join[{-(1/hh[[1]]) + hh[[1]]/c^2}, 
   Table[-((2  hh[[i - 1]] (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]))/(3 c^2)) + (-1 + 
      ww[[i - 1]])/( hh[[i - 1]] ww[[i - 1]]), {i, 2, m4 - 1}], {1/
    hh[[Length[hh]]]}];
A1d3 = Join[{1/hh[[1]]}, 
   Table[(3/ww[[i - 1]] + (hh[[i - 1]]^2 (-2 + 5 ww[[i - 1]]))/c^2)/(
    3 hh[[i - 1]] (1 + ww[[i - 1]])), {i, 2, m4 - 1}]];
(*2nd*)
A3d1 = Join[
   Table[(3 hh[[
         i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])^2 (-1 + 
          ww[[i - 1]]) + (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 - 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 ww[[i - 1]]) - 
       hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
          hh[[i - 1]]) (1 + (-3 + ww[[i - 1]]) ww[[i - 1]]))/(c^2 hh[[
        i - 1]]^2 (-1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) (1 + 
         hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) ((1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) + 
         ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m4 - 1}], {0}];
A2d1 = Join[{(2 (3/hh[[1]]^2 + (5 + 2 (-2 + ww[[1]]) ww[[1]])/c^2))/(
    3 (1 + ww[[1]]))}, Table[
    ((1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 + 3 hh[[i - 1]]^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) - (2 c^2 + 
          3 hh[[i - 1]]^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
             hh[[i - 1]]) (3 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]))) ww[[
         i - 1]] + 
       hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) ww[[
         i - 1]]^2)/(c^2 hh[[
        i - 1]]^2 (-1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) (1 + 
         ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m4 - 1}], {-4/c^2}];
A2d2 = Join[{-4/c^2, (
    2 (-(3/hh[[1]]^2) + (-2 + ww[[1]] - 2 ww[[1]]^2)/c^2))/(
    3 ww[[1]])}, Table[
    1/(c^2 hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) ww[[
       i - 1]]) (hh[[
         i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])^2 (-1 + 
          ww[[i - 1]]) + (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 - 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 ww[[i - 1]]) - (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
          hh[[i - 1]]) (2 c^2 + hh[[i - 1]]^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (-1 + ww[[i - 1]]) ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m4 - 1}], {2/c^2}];
A2d3 = Join[{2/c^2, (
    6 c^2 + 2 hh[[1]]^2 (2 + ww[[1]] (-4 + 5 ww[[1]])))/(
    3 c^2 hh[[1]]^2 ww[[1]] (1 + ww[[1]]))}, Table[
    ((1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) (2 c^2 + 
          hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) - 
       hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/
             hh[[i - 1]]) (3 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]))) ww[[
         i - 1]] + 
       3 hh[[i - 1]]^2 (1 + (1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]])) ww[[
         i - 1]]^2)/(c^2 hh[[i - 1]]^2 ww[[
        i - 1]] (1 + ww[[i - 1]]) ((1 + hh[[i - 2]]/hh[[i - 1]]) + 
         ww[[i - 1]]))
    , {i, 3, m4 - 1}]];

dudw = Chop@
   SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> A1d2, Band[{2, 1}] -> A1d1, 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> A1d3}, {m4, m4}];
d2udw2 = Chop@
   SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> A2d2, Band[{2, 1}] -> A2d1, 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> A2d3, Band[{3, 1}] -> A3d1}, {m4, m4}];

(****************BUILDING THE SYSTEM MATRIX********************)

B = SparseArray[
   +(1/2 sigmaR^2 DR.(Id - DR)).KroneckerProduct[d2udx2, Idy, Idz, Idw]
    + (1/2 sigmar^2 Dr).KroneckerProduct[Idx, d2udy2, Idz, Idw]
    + (1/2 sigmay^2)*KroneckerProduct[Idx, Idy, d2udz2, Idw]
    + (1/2 sigmaz^2 Dz^2)*KroneckerProduct[Idx, Idy, Idz, d2udw2]
    + ((roRr*sigmaR*sigmar)*Sqrt[(DR.(Id - DR)).Dr]).KroneckerProduct[
      dudx, dudy, Idz, Idw]
    + ((roRz*sigmaR*sigmaz)*(Dz.Sqrt[DR.(Id - DR)])).KroneckerProduct[
      dudx, Idy, Idz, dudw]
    + ((rorz*sigmar*sigmaz)*(Dz.Sqrt[Dr])).KroneckerProduct[Idx, dudy,
       Idz, dudw]
    + ((roRy*sigmaR*sigmay)*(Sqrt[DR.(Id - DR)])).KroneckerProduct[
      dudx, Idy, dudz, Idw]
    + ((rory*sigmar*sigmay)*(Sqrt[Dr])).KroneckerProduct[Idx, dudy, 
      dudz, Idw]
    + ((royz*sigmay*sigmaz)*Dz).KroneckerProduct[Idx, Idy, dudz, dudw]
    + (a*(b*Id - DR)).KroneckerProduct[dudx, Idy, Idz, Idw]
    + (a1 (b1*Id - Dr)).KroneckerProduct[Idx, dudy, Idz, Idw]
    + ((r*Id - Dr).Dz).KroneckerProduct[Idx, Idy, Idz, dudw]
    + (κ (θ*Id - Dy)).KroneckerProduct[Idx, Idy, dudz, 
      Idw]
    - (r*Id + Dy2)
    - gammaz*(Dy2.(Dz.KroneckerProduct[Idx, Idy, Idz, dudw]))
   ];


payoff = Flatten@
   Table[nw[[l]], {i, 1, m1}, {j, 1, m2}, {k, 1, m3}, {l, 1, m4}];
initc = Thread[v[0] == payoff];


(*Imposing the boundaries*)
index1 = Flatten[
   Table[{i, j, k, l}, {i, 1, m1}, {j, 1, m2}, {k, 1, m3}, {l, 1, 
     m4}], 3];

(*Boundary when R tends to Subscript[R, max]*)
U12[t_] = Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 1, m1}];
unk = D[Last[U12[t]], t];
unk2 = Drop[D[Take[U12[t], -4], t], -1];
Last[Simplify@
   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, nx, U12[t], 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]];
% == 0;
FullSimplify@(unk /. Solve[D[%, t], unk]);
{b111, A111} = Normal@CoefficientArrays[%, unk2];
A121 = First[A111];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[1]] == m1), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete111 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[1]] == m1 - 1), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete222 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0]; // AbsoluteTiming
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[1]] == m1 - 2), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete333 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[1]] == m1 - 3), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete444 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
B[[delete111]] = (A121[[3]] B[[delete222]] + 
     A121[[2]] B[[delete333]] + 
     A121[[1]] B[[delete444]]); // AbsoluteTiming

(*Boundary when R tends to Subscript[R, min]*)
U12[t_] = Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 1, m1}];
unk = D[First[U12[t]], t];
unk2 = Drop[D[Take[U12[t], 4], t], 1];
First[Simplify@
   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, nx, U12[t], 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]];
% == 0;
FullSimplify@(unk /. Solve[D[%, t], unk]);
{b111, A111} = Normal@CoefficientArrays[%, unk2];
A121 = First[A111];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[1]] == 1), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete111 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[1]] == 2), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete222 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[1]] == 3), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete333 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[1]] == 4), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete444 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
B[[delete111]] = (A121[[1]] B[[delete222]] + 
    A121[[2]] B[[delete333]] + A121[[3]] B[[delete444]]);

(*Boundary when r tends to Subscript[r, max]*)
U12[t_] = Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 1, m2}];
unk = D[Last[U12[t]], t];
unk2 = Drop[D[Take[U12[t], -4], t], -1];
Last[Simplify@
   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, ny, U12[t], 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]];
% == 0;
FullSimplify@(unk /. Solve[D[%, t], unk]);
{b111, A111} = Normal@CoefficientArrays[%, unk2];
A121 = First[A111];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[2]] == m2), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete111 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[2]] == m2 - 1), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete222 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[2]] == m2 - 2), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete333 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[2]] == m2 - 3), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete444 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
B[[delete111]] = (A121[[3]] B[[delete222]] + 
    A121[[2]] B[[delete333]] + A121[[1]] B[[delete444]]);

(*Boundary when r tends to Subscript[r, min]*)
U12[t_] = Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 1, m2}];
unk = D[First[U12[t]], t];
unk2 = Drop[D[Take[U12[t], 4], t], 1];
First[Simplify@
   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, ny, U12[t], 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]];
% == 0;
FullSimplify@(unk /. Solve[D[%, t], unk]);
{b111, A111} = Normal@CoefficientArrays[%, unk2];
A121 = First[A111];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[2]] == 1), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete111 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[2]] == 2), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete222 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[2]] == 3), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete333 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[2]] == 4), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete444 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
B[[delete111]] = (A121[[1]] B[[delete222]] + 
    A121[[2]] B[[delete333]] + A121[[3]] B[[delete444]]);

(*Boundary when y tends to Subscript[y, max]*)
U12[t_] = Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 1, m3}];
unk = D[Last[U12[t]], t];
unk2 = Drop[D[Take[U12[t], -4], t], -1];
Last[Simplify@
   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, nz, U12[t], 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]];
% == 0;
FullSimplify@(unk /. Solve[D[%, t], unk]);
{b111, A111} = Normal@CoefficientArrays[%, unk2];
A1210 = First[A111];
pos20 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[3]] == m3), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete1110 = DeleteCases[pos20, 0];
pos20 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[3]] == m3 - 1), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete2220 = DeleteCases[pos20, 0];
pos20 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[3]] == m3 - 2), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete3330 = DeleteCases[pos20, 0];
pos20 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[3]] == m3 - 3), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete4440 = DeleteCases[pos20, 0];
B[[delete1110]] = (A1210[[3]] B[[delete2220]] + 
    A1210[[2]] B[[delete3330]] + A1210[[1]] B[[delete4440]]);

(*Boundary when y tends to Subscript[y, min]*)
U12[t_] = Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 1, m3}];
unk = D[First[U12[t]], t];
unk2 = Drop[D[Take[U12[t], 4], t], 1];
First[Simplify@
   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, nz, U12[t], 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]];
% == 0;
FullSimplify@(unk /. Solve[D[%, t], unk]);
{b111, A111} = Normal@CoefficientArrays[%, unk2];
A121 = First[A111];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[3]] == 1), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete111 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[3]] == 2), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete222 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[3]] == 3), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete333 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[3]] == 4), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete444 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
B[[delete111]] = (A121[[1]] B[[delete222]] + 
    A121[[2]] B[[delete333]] + A121[[3]] B[[delete444]]);

(*Boundary when z tends to Subscript[z, max]*)
U12[t_] = Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 1, m4}];
unk = D[Last[U12[t]], t];
unk2 = Drop[D[Take[U12[t], -4], t], -1];
Last[Simplify@
   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, nw, U12[t], 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]];
% == 0;
FullSimplify@(unk /. Solve[D[%, t], unk]);
{b111, A111} = Normal@CoefficientArrays[%, unk2];
A121 = First[A111];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[4]] == m4), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete111 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[4]] == m4 - 1), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete222 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[4]] == m4 - 2), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete333 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[4]] == m4 - 3), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, 
    Length@index1}];
delete444 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
B[[delete111]] = (A121[[3]] B[[delete222]] + 
    A121[[2]] B[[delete333]] + A121[[1]] B[[delete444]]);

(*Boundary when z tends to Subscript[z, min]*)
U12[t_] = Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 1, m4}];
unk = D[First[U12[t]], t];
unk2 = Drop[D[Take[U12[t], 4], t], 1];
First[Simplify@
   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, nw, U12[t], 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]];
% == 0;
FullSimplify@(unk /. Solve[D[%, t], unk]);
{b111, A111} = Normal@CoefficientArrays[%, unk2];
A121 = First[A111];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[4]] == 1), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete111 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[4]] == 2), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete222 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[4]] == 3), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete333 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
pos2 = Table[ind1 = index1[[l]];
   If[(ind1[[4]] == 4), var1[l] = l, var1[l] = 0], {l, Length@index1}];
delete444 = DeleteCases[pos2, 0];
B[[delete111]] = (A121[[1]] B[[delete222]] + 
    A121[[2]] B[[delete333]] + A121[[3]] B[[delete444]]);
8

B = SparseArray[B];

k1 = .05;
Monitor[
   lines = NDSolve[
     {D[v[t], t] == B.v[t], v[0] == initc[[All, 2]]}, v[t], {t, 0, TT},
     Method -> {"FixedStep", "StepSize" -> k1, 
       Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta",
         "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, "StiffnessTest" -> False}},
     PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5,
     EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])],
   monitor]; // AbsoluteTiming

s = v[t] /. lines[[1]];
solution1[time_] := s /. t -> time
sol2 = solution1[TT];

ClearAll[Idx, Idy, Idz, Idw, dudx, dudy, dudz, d2udx2, d2udy2, d2udz2,
   hh, ww, delete, delete1, delete11];
set1 = Chop@
   Flatten[Table[{Flatten@{origrid[[i]], sol2[[i]]}}, {i, 1, 
      Length[payoff]}], 1];
gg = Interpolation@set1;

NN = 10;
m = 120;
tInterval = Range[0, TT, TT/m];
h = (TT/m)/NN;

leng = Length[payoff];
tab1 = Table[i, {i, size}];

Aa = Parallelize@Table[
     setsol1 = Table[
       g1 = With[{current = solution1[input]},
         Interpolation@Threshold@Flatten[

            Table[{Flatten@{origrid[[i]], (current)[[i]]}}, {i, 
              leng}], 1]
         ];
       g1[e1, 0.03, -4.089, e]
       ,
       {input, Table[(tInterval[[j]] + k*h), {k, NN}]}
       ];
     h*Sum[setsol1[[k]], {k, NN}]
     , {j, m}]; // AbsoluteTiming

t2 = AbsoluteTime[] - t1;
Print["The whole computational time is = ", t2];
```

I know this code is large but my problem is only about its last part (when $m=120$, i.e., for calculating the list for `Aa`).

How can we accelerate with Interpolation[] inside a loop? In other words, how can we make fast repeated interpolations on very large 4D grids?

I have now used the parallel command `ParallelTable[]` which requires 14.5 seconds on my system. Noting that in my actual tests, I wish to increase the number of discretization points of the PDE which lead to higher CPU time. Therefore, I will be thankful if someone could give me some hint to improve the performance.
Can we "Compile[]" a list of vectors?
Can we do some part in the GPU using Mathematica CUDA applicability?

Comment: What do you calculate with this code, what should be the result?

Comment: After solving the PDE, I must find the values of the solution at a special location of the domain (e1, 0.03, -4.089, e) for different times. This must be done $m$ times which $m$ comes from a financial application. Here, it shows bi-monthly payment of a quanto CDS par spread. So, the final result of the `Aa` is a list of numbers/values/par-spreads, which I finally do some operations (such as addition) on this list.

Comment: The more I think about this, the angrier I become. The actual problem is about `Interpolation` and the fact that it takes much longer to generate an `InterpolatingFunction` than to evaluate it once. This problem could have been illustrated in about a dozen lines of code. The whole mess that is needed to generate `solution1` **is not needed at all to demonstrate the problem**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP does not care at all to produce a minimal example.

Comment: If the whole mess `solution1[]` is not needed, so how I can find the values in the special location of the domain by changing time (the argument of `solution1[]`)? Maybe, I should do only one interpolation on a larger set, i.e., with 6 variables, 5 are the domain grid and time and the last one is the value of `solution1[]`? And what do you mean by "minimal example?" The computation of `Aa` is time-consuming! That's it! The outputs are correct but timely.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I think you can optimize this problem.

Comment: @Fazlollah Can you explain the origin of this problem? Are there any published articles on this topic?

Comment: Yes, please see this link https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07133. We are computing a similar 4D PDE to the one coming after (23) in page (10) of the paper in this link. The financial model behind these Mathematica lines are quite heavy, but with the help of Mathematica the whole process is getting possible.

Comment: @Fazlollah Thank you for the good code. After all the improvements, it takes only 1.3 seconds on my laptop. It can still be improved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the *actual* problem, condensed in only a couple of lines:

```
m1 = 10; m2 = 10; m3 = 10; m4 = 10;
dims = {10, 10, 10, 10};
grids = {
   Subdivide[0., 1., m1 - 1],
   Subdivide[0., 1., m2 - 1],
   Subdivide[-6., 0., m3 - 1],
   Subdivide[0., 4., m4 - 1]
   };
origrid = Tuples[grids];
leng = Length[origrid];
pt = Developer`ToPackedArray[{0.45, 0.03, -4.089, 1.15}];

vals = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, leng];
g = Interpolation@ Flatten[Table[{Flatten@{origrid[[i]], vals[[i]]}}, {i, leng}], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
result = g @@ pt; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.04719
>
> 0.000149

That is: We need to evaluate a certain `InterpolatingFunction` `g` computed from values `vals` on a regular, rectangular grid `origrid` only at a single fixed point `pt`. The values of `vals` may change over time, but the point `pt` is fixed. As one can see, creating the interpolating function takes about 300 times as long as evaluating it.

A first step is to replace the suspiciously complicated way of building the array that is fed to `Interpolation`:

```
g = Interpolation@Join[origrid, Partition[vals, 1], 2]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.011582

This speeds things up already by a factor of 4.

## Avoiding `Interpolation`

Denote the the grid points by $P_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}$ with $1 \leq i_k \leq n_k$ and the functions values that we want to interpolate by $v_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}$ with $1 \leq i_k \leq n_k$. Denote by $x$ a point in $\mathbb{R}^4$ on which we want to evaluate the function $g$, where the latter satisfies $g(P_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}) = v_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}$.

It depends somehow on the interpolation scheme that one wants to use. IIRC, `Interpolation` uses tensor product splines of order $3$ by default. That means, the stencil of a point evalutation has size $4 = 3 + 1$ per dimension. So what one should do:

The point $x$ lies in a certain cell of the rectangular grid. Denote the grid point to the "lower left" by  $P_{j_1,j_2,j_3,j_4}$.

Then $g(x)$ depends only on the values
$$v_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}\quad \text{with} \quad j_k -1 \leq i_k \leq j_k+2, \quad k \in \{1,\dotsc,4\}.$$

More precisely, one has
$$ g(x) = \sum_{j_k -1 \leq i_k \leq j_k+2} \omega_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4} \, v_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4},
\quad
\text{where}
\quad
\omega_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4} := \varphi_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}(x)
$$
and where $\varphi_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}$ is the interpolating function that satisfies $\varphi_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}(P_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}) = 1$ and that vanishes on all other grid points. The weights $\omega_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}$ have to be calculcated once and only for the grid points in the stencil, hence on only $256= (3+1)^4$ points.

Since tensor product splines are employed, one has
$$
\omega_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}
=
\varphi_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}(x)
=
\varphi_{1,i_1}(x_1) \, \varphi_{2,i_2}(x_2) \, \varphi_{3,i_3}(x_3) \, \varphi_{4,i_4}(x_4)
$$
where $\varphi_{k,i}$ is the $i$-th interpolating in the $k$-th direction.

This can be implemented as follows:

```
w = Flatten[
   KroneckerProduct @@ MapThread[
     SparseArray@Interpolation[Transpose[{#1, IdentityMatrix[#2, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]}]]@#3 &,
     {grids, dims, pt}
     ]
   ];
idx = Flatten[w["NonzeroPositions"]];
w = w["NonzeroValues"];
```

Now, $g(x)$ can be evaluated as follows:

```
result2 = vals[[idx]].w; // AbsoluteTiming // First
result2 - result
```

> 0.000015
>
> 0.

Thus, the evaluatation is about 3000 times faster than generating the `InterpolatingFunction` `g` even 10 times faster than just evaluating it.

It becomes even more impressive if one performs evaluations in bulk, so that machine acceleration of matrix-vector products can be exploited (and *Mathematica*'s interpretation overhead can be avoided):

```
vals = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {120, leng}];
result = Table[
     With[{current = vals[[j]]},
      Interpolation[Flatten[Table[{Flatten@{origrid[[i]], current[[i]]}}, {i, leng}], 1]] @@ pt
      ],
     {j, 1, 120}
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
result2 = vals[[All, idx]].w; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[result - result2]]
```

> 5.25747
>
> 0.000176
>
> 4.996*10^-16

This is almost a 30000-fold speed-up.

## Addendum

After redefining `solution1` appropriately, list `Aa` can then be obtained this way:

```
s = NDSolveValue[
    {
     D[v[t], t] == B.v[t],
     v[0] == initc[[All, 2]]
     },
    v,
    {t, 0, TT},
    Method -> {
      "FixedStep", "StepSize" -> k1, 
      Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
        "StiffnessTest" -> False}
      },
    PrecisionGoal -> 5,
    AccuracyGoal -> 5
    ];
(* Creating an interpolation function that returns only the required entries of `s` *)
solution1 = ReplacePart[s, 4 -> s[[4, All, All, idx]]];
Aafast = Dot[
     solution1[Outer[Plus, tInterval[[1 ;; m]], Range[h, NN h, h]]],
     w,
     ConstantArray[h, NN]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[Aafast - Aa]]
```

> 0.009964
>
> 1.38778*10^-17

On my machine, this runs about 2200 times faster than the original code for `Aa`.
The new definition of `solution1` enforces that only the relevant entries of the large vector a computed. Anyways, `solution1` is still the bottleneck here.

Comment: +1 It works. The last table brakes `Aa = Table[
  h*Sum[g[(tInterval[[j]] + k*h)], {k, NN}], {j, m}]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you. I think I fixed it in my most recent edit.

Comment: Fantastic 5436x acceleration on my laptop. Henrik, you are a genius!

Comment: Huh, thank you, Alex. =D

Comment: A step by step useful optimization of the code. This is indeed great Henrik. Thanks a lot. I got a query. Why the length of each output/vector coming from your `solution1[]` is 256 (even when we change $m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4$)! Consider that I wish to plot the solution at the final time `solution1[TT]`, so in my old and slow implementation, the length of the code was as same as the length of the `origrid` (for any $m_i$) and I was able to plot the solution while now I cannot! Can you please write some hints about this as well.

Comment: +1. So, you voted to close and then answered anyways ;) That's what I call an addict... perhaps we need a Alco-SE-lics Anonymous ;-) Well done.

Comment: @user21 It was a long, boring weekend you know... ;)

Comment: @Fazlollah The 256 comes from the fact that the stencil of the interpolation has size $4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4$. That depends only on the order of the iterpolation scheme, not on the size of the grid. But I changed the code so that the result of `NDSolveValue` is stored in `s` (this is now what the old `solution1` was). So if you want to plot the solution, just use `s` instead.

Comment: Great. This question/answer can be useful for many practitioners in finance who have similar problems when the size of their models is high.